# Salesforce Nonprofit Starter Pack - Company field on Leads

Tags: web2lead, nonprofit-starter-pack

We have just installed the NFP Starter pack for Salesforce, and have come across a problem when we use web to lead.

We allow users to apply for membership by filling in a web to lead form. The problem is, that Company is a required field on leads. If the prospect fills in that field, it would create a normal account, not a household account when I convert the lead.

Has anyone come across this problem before?
Tia.

Answer (score 0):

The npsp help link for converting leads to household is [here](https://powerofus.force.com/articles/Resource/NPSP-Convert-a-Lead-to-a-Contact)